# Expression Language with CDI not work

Tags: glassfish, websphere, el, cdi

i have a simple ear file that includes a war. I have only one Named- Bean and one xhtml. 
On glassfish all works fine. But on websphere it does not works. 
I does not works mean all EL- Tag will be ignored. I can reproduce this in glassfish when i delete my beans.xml in /WEB- INF. I tried to put the beans.xml in every single folder.

And i read this (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1301_stephen/1301_stephen.html):

> The beans.xml file must be placed in one of these locations:
>       For a library JAR, EJB JAR, application client JAR or RAR archive, it needs to be in the META-INF directory.
>       The WEB-INF/classes directory of a WAR.
>       For a directory in the JVM classpath containing classes, the code will be scanned if the beans.xml file is located the META-INF sub-directory.

But nothing works. When i use @ManagedBean and Faces Session Scope instead all works fine.
I don't know what i can do else. Please help.

Here my example code and my structures:

XHTML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>

</h:head>

<h:body>
 <h:form id="tableform">
    <h:outputText value="TEST"/>
    <h:outputText value="#{personBean.helloWorld}"/>
    <p:commandButton value="#{personBean.helloWorld}"/>
</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Bean:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class PersonBean implements Serializable{

private String helloWorld;


@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    setHelloWorld("HELLO WORLD");
}


public String getHelloWorld() {
    return helloWorld;
}


public void setHelloWorld(String helloWorld) {
    this.helloWorld = helloWorld;
}
}
```

**Structure**:

Ear
-Meta-Inf
--Application.xml
-WAR
--WEB-INF
---beans.xml

But i tried to put it in WEB-INF/classes, META-INF, META-INF from ear. Nothing works. :(

Result on Glassfish with beans.xml:

[image]

Result on Websphere / Glassfish without beans.xml:

[image]

I get no exception or error or something else.

Comment: I don't understand. It works when you put a beans.xml file and it doesn't when you don't. It's the expected behavior...

Comment: The delete from beans.xml was only to demonstrate the error. On websphere it doesnt works with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebSphere 8.x bundles JSF implementation (MyFaces) and only that default implementation works with CDI. You need to have `beans.xml` in `WEB-INF` folder.

However based on your page fragment, you are using custom one (PrimeFaces).
Check this page for more details : [CDI integration with JavaServer Faces](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/cweb_cdi_integration.html?lang=en)

Comment: hmm... okay we had a shared lib with mojarra on it. I think there is the problem. I'll try something in this direction.